# Displaying information from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a forum. I would like to simple have php or html pull some info from my mysql database and put it on the screen. Below is the table... do I use php for this? Thanks!

```
`forum_topic` varchar(65) 
`forum_prefix` varchar(65) 
`forum_title` varchar(65) 
`forum_content` longtext
```

Comment: [Take a look](http://tinyurl.com/dj8n7n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with php and mysql, it is not quite so straight forward though, you might want to look at this:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch/

or this :

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/12.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be done in your php code.

Comment: Do I use an html form and send the form action to a php script?

Comment: I would like it displayed as a list... like the page will grab all of the db information and display in a table/form

Comment: So when the page loads you will call some php function that queries your database.